# display local time (not server time) in email when sending it using c# batch

Tags: c#, email, batch-file, stored-procedures, email-client

How do i display local time (not server time) in email when sending it using c# batch?
Scenario: I send an email in toronto (3:30 AM) and my server is in los angeles (12:30 AM)

The email content will display something like this: "I registered a bugs at 3:30AM local time".

How do I do this in my c# batch?

Comment: What do you mean by "I send an email in Toronto"? You haven't given us enough context about what's running where to help you. We have no idea what kind of batch you're talking about, or what kind of app you're writing.

Comment: I think you can put time headers with c# and it will automatically be converted to the local time when it's recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not standardize it and use DateTime.UtcNow?